# Перенос базы postgresql с Windows на linux

Tags: база-данных, postgresql

Добрый день!

Уже несколько дней не могу решить проблему переноса базы данных *Postgresql* с *Windows* машины на *Linux*. Проблема с кодировками.

Версия *PostgreSQL* на *Windows* машине и на *linux*: 9.4

База данных на *Windows* имеет следующие параметры:

- Кодировка: UTF-8
- Сопоставление: Russian_Russian.1251
- Тип символа: Russian_Russian.1251

  postgres=# \l

Список баз данных

```
Имя | Владелец | Кодировка | LC_COLLATE | LC_CTYPE | Права доступа<br>
-----------+----------+-----------+---------------------+---------------------+-----------------------<br>
postgres | postgres | UTF8 | Russian_Russia.1251 | Russian_Russia.1251 |<br>
project | postgres | UTF8 | Russian_Russia.1251 | Russian_Russia.1251 |<br>
template0 | postgres | UTF8 | Russian_Russia.1251 | Russian_Russia.1251 | =c/postgres +<br>
| | | | | postgres=CTc/postgres<br>
template1 | postgres | UTF8 | Russian_Russia.1251 | Russian_Russia.1251 | =c/postgres +<br>
| | | | | postgres=CTc/postgres<br>
database | postgres | UTF8 | Russian_Russia.1251 | Russian_Russia.1251 |
```

При попытке создать базу данных на *Linux*, с такими же параметрами выдается:

```
postgres=# CREATE DATABASE database WITH OWNER = postgres ENCODING = 'UTF-8' LC_COLLATE = 'ru_RU.cp1251' LC_CTYPE = 'ru_RU.cp1251' CONNECTION LIMIT = -1;
```

> ОШИБКА: кодировка "UTF8" не соответствует локали "ru_RU.cp1251"
>   ПОДРОБНОСТИ: Для выбранного параметра LC_CTYPE требуется кодировка "WIN1251".

То есть либо всё должно быть в *UTF-8*, либо в *WIN1251*.

Пробовал создавать базу, где кодировка, сопоставление и тип в *UTF-8* и перенести дамп в нее. С виду все хорошо, база заливается без ошибок, но потом в ходе работы обнаруживаются косяки, не может найти и подхватить значения в некоторых местах.

Вопрос. Почему для *Windows* нормально, когда база данных в одной кодировке, а сопоставление и тип в другой, а для линукса это страшный грех?

И как быть в такой ситуации? Как перенести базу данных из *Windows* в *Linux* с такими параметрами?

Помогите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В документации к postgres-у отмечается эта его особенность в разделе 22.3. Character Set Support (версия 9.2). В 9.4 ничего не изменилось:

> An important restriction, however, is that each database's character
>   set must be compatible with the database's LC_CTYPE (character
>   classification) and LC_COLLATE (string sort order) locale settings.
>   For C or POSIX locale, any character set is allowed, but for other
>   locales there is only one character set that will work correctly. (On
>   Windows, however, UTF-8 encoding can be used with any locale.)

Думаю это можно принять за ответ на на вопрос почему.
А вот как быть дальше думайте сами. Можно отменить переезд на линух, перекодировать базу, изменить encoding или lc_* на виндовсе, ещё чего-нибудь.

Каким образом данные экспортируются: Бинарный формат pg_dump или текстовый?
Попробуйте бинарный, который восстанавливается pg_restore.

А почему никто из посетителей стековерфлова не читает стандартных руководств?
Чукча - не читатель, чукча - программист?